# How to rotate text without rotating the text-view?

Tags: android, textview, rotation

I want to rotate just the text inside a text-view, not the text-view itself.

Currently I have something like:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="GOO GOO GA GA"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/boo1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/boo2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boo3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.428" />
```

But this of course rotates the entire text-view, with the text inside. I already drew a vertical text-view on the Design screen and I don't want that to rotate because of constraint reasons.